# Multiple "Security Testing" within a single server?

Tags: android-netrunner

Can I choose the same server for two copies of [Security Testing](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05048) and get 4 credits from the first run on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose same server for multiple Security Testings, but you still would get credits from only 1 of them. Security Testing effect is a replacement effect which replaces access step. You have one access step per run and it can be replaced with any **one** applicable effect of your choice. So they all would trigger same time, but only 1 will get to resolve.

Moreover, other Security Testings wouldn't work on subsequent runs on the same server this turn, because it woudn't be a **first** successful run anymore and they can't meet their trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You will only get 2 credits, since [Security Testing](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05048) replaces the access with credit gain, and once that is replaced other effects don't have an access to replace.

Other effects that replace card access would need you to pick one, like [Patron](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/10063), [Bank Job](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/20033) or [Retrieval Run](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/20003). Cards that don't impact the access still work, like [Dirty Laundry](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03052).

Some of these cards only work the first time you make that run, so the first run on that server will meet the condition, preventing the card from working on every other run that turn.

It's worth noting that while [Eater](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07040) prevents access, it does so by lowering your number of accessed cards to 0, so [Eater](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07040) will not prevent [Security Testing](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05048), or any of the other mentioned instead of access cards, from working, since you are still replacing an access of 0 with credit gain, draw, install, etc.